LFSR with the initial state $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=(00\dots{}01)$
Given an $n$-stage LFSR, $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of LFSR and how to prove the period of $p(x)$ equals the period of the initial state $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=(00\dots{}01)$.
If $p(x)$ is a primitive polynomial and the initial state is a non-zero state, I know the output sequence  will have the same period as the period of $p(x)$. But in general condition, I don't know how to prove it.

Hint: LFSR states move from one point to another, so, a state is either in a cycle or not. If the LFSR is maximal, means that it has full period, except the all-zero state.

It is good that the OP does not know how to prove the general  statement, because the general statement is false.

Well, how to find a counterexample to deny it?@DilipSarwate

Disclaimer: In crypto we normally use primitive generating polynomials with nice properties but I took your question to be more general.
If the polynomial is not primitive the relationship need not hold. The period of the impulse response sequence ( resulting from $[0,\ldots,0,1]$) is in general longer than other possible periods for other initial loadings.
Example: Consider $s_t=s_{t-1}\oplus s_{t-5}:$
The initial condition $[0,0,0,0,1]$ gives the impulse response sequence with period 21.
$$
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
$$
The initial condition $[1,1,0,1,1]$ gives the sequence
$$[ 1, 1, 0; 1, 1, 0]$$
with period 3.
It can be proved that periods of other sequences obtainable divide those of the impulse response sequence. A treatment is in Chapter 6 of Lidl and Niederreiter's Introduction to Finite Fields and Their Applications.
So a possible crypto application (for not so high security, such a tactical comms application) might be to select a very high degree polynomial at random (key choice being polynomial choice) and load it with the impulse response loading $[0,0,\ldots,1]$ ensuring maximum period for that generator. You can then generate arbitrary phases as needed.

clearly, hw.....

I misinterpreted the question, I guess, if you're right. he/she does say "But in general condition, I don't know how to prove it."
